# Composer make my web dead after installation

Tags: error, composer

today i installed Composer to my SSH. But after installation my web died.
I got this error

```
Warning: require(/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/composer/../zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/composer/../zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php' (include_path='/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70